# How to append a leaf to the root node of a decision tree, after having traversed through it?

Tags: python, tree

I am working on a taxonomy tree, which is a decision tree that has an initial node. The initial node is a question which has a yes or no answer and then the tree progresses to the next node based on the answer. Each leaf is an identification question which confirms that a particular object with a given name has been identified. 
But, for the case that the item does not exist in the tree, I would input the item's name and then input a question that differentiated between the previous item, and my item. So how would I insert a new node into the middle of the current tree in the function?

My code for this function is given below:

```
def identify_thing(tree):
    node_type = tree[0]
    if node_type == "D":
      (question, yes_tree, no_tree) = tree[1:]
      yes_answer = get_yes_no(question)
      if yes_answer:
        identify_thing(yes_tree)
      else:
        identify_thing(no_tree)
    elif node_type == "I":
      name = tree[1]
      question = "Is it a {}?".format(name)
      yes_answer = get_yes_no(question)
      if yes_answer:
        print("{} Identified!".format(name))
      else:
        print("I don't know what it is.")
        new_name = get_nonblank_str("What is it?")
        new_question = get_nonblank_str("Give me a question where yes means 
                       a '{}'" " and no means a '{}'".format(new_name, name))
        # this is where I am trying to insert the code for updating the tree
```

Thank you!